# Using variables in get_columns_in_relation dbt function

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I'm fairly new to macros and variables in dbt so apologize if this is really straightforward but I'm attempting the below but it's not recognizing the `{{customer_dataset}}.{{table_name}}` part

```
{%- set table_name = 'orders' -%}

{%- set customer_dataset = customer.id -%}

{%- set columns = adapter.get_columns_in_relation(`{{customer_dataset}}.{{table_name}}`) -%}
```

How do I do this properly if I want to dynamically loop through a bunch of tables for the `get_columns_in_relation` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, [don't nest your curlies](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/dont-nest-your-curlies).

Second, `get_columns_in_relation` expects a [Relation](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-classes#relation), not a string. A Relation is the thing returned by `{{ ref() }}` or `{{ source() }}`, so it's easiest to get a Relation from a model name, not a database identifier. If you want to use a table in your database that isn't a dbt model, create a [source](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/sources) for it first.

In short, your code should probably look like this:

```
{%- set columns = adapter.get_columns_in_relation(source(customer_dataset, table_name)) -%}
```

Comment: Really appreciate the answer! I didn't quite know how to turn the table into a source and ref only seems to take a string as an argument so I ended up doing this which worked as well:

`{%- set source_relation = adapter.get_relation(database=this_database, schema=this_dataset, identifier=this_table) -%}`

And then

`{%- set columns = adapter.get_columns_in_relation(source_relation) -%}`